# Conditionally exclude a field from JSON serialization in implementation in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a project, and I have a Data Transfer Object (DTO) class that contains the fields I am returning in the API responses. However, there are cases where I don't want a specific field to be included in the response object.

For example:

```
class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private int age; // I want to exclude 'age' from the response in some cases.
 }
```

How can I conditionally exclude the 'age' field in certain cases? Are there any annotations or design patterns that I can apply to achieve this behavior?

Comment: Return a different type? What are the "conditions"? Can you make it an `Integer` and exclude `null` from being serialized?

Comment: I can pass a boolean parameter to dynamically exclude a specific field; this is just an example. I already have a class, and I want to create a variation of the same class with an additional field without duplicating code

Comment: If i change the class that already exists, it may break something. I want to create my class to exclude a targeted field. Without repeating all the code

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider the option of @knitti from the comments,

or you can use the `@JsonView` feature: https://reflectoring.io/jackson-jsonview-tutorial/